# Transform attribute affects other children in SVG

Tags: svg

I'm trying to apply a transform on one of the elements of a SVG but the transform affects the other children as well.

The transform applied on the path element below affects the two lines as well. How can I prevent this from happening?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" height="20" width="20">
     <line stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_1" y2="15" x2="15" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none"/>
     <line transform="rotate(90) " stroke-linecap="undefined" stroke-linejoin="undefined" id="svg_2" y2="15" x2="15" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#fff" fill="none"/>
     <path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="27" fill="#ffffff" transform="translate(10 10) scale(0.6)" d="M512 320s-64 92.65-64 128c0 35.35 28.66 64 64 64s64-28.65 64-64-64-128-64-128zm-9.37-102.94L294.94 9.37C288.69 3.12 280.5 0 272.31 0s-16.38 3.12-22.62 9.37l-81.58 81.58L81.93 4.76c-6.25-6.25-16.38-6.25-22.62 0L36.69 27.38c-6.24 6.25-6.24 16.38 0 22.62l86.19 86.18-94.76 94.76c-37.49 37.48-37.49 98.26 0 135.75l117.19 117.19c18.74 18.74 43.31 28.12 67.87 28.12 24.57 0 49.13-9.37 67.87-28.12l221.57-221.57c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.75.01-45.25zm-116.22 70.97H65.93c1.36-3.84 3.57-7.98 7.43-11.83l13.15-13.15 81.61-81.61 58.6 58.6c12.49 12.49 32.75 12.49 45.24 0s12.49-32.75 0-45.24l-58.6-58.6 58.95-58.95 162.44 162.44-48.34 48.34z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: The other two lines are so tiny compared to the path they're basically invisible next to it. In addition those lines are both white so they don't show up much on a white background. Maybe the two lines you're looking at are actually parts of the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented @Robert Longson, there should be no line transformation during the transformation of the patch.
Image is very small.

To see the immutability of the lines during the transformation of the `path`, I increased the image size `width = "400"` and `height = "400"` and painted the lines in red.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" height="400" width="400">
     
     <line   id="svg_1" y2="150" x2="150" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
     
  <line transform="rotate(90)"  id="svg_2" y2="15" x2="15" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="red" fill="none"/> 
  
  <path stroke="#000000" transform="translate(10 10) scale(0.6)" stroke-width="27" fill="#ffffff"  d="M512 320s-64 92.65-64 128c0 35.35 28.66 64 64 64s64-28.65 64-64-64-128-64-128zm-9.37-102.94L294.94 9.37C288.69 3.12 280.5 0 272.31 0s-16.38 3.12-22.62 9.37l-81.58 81.58L81.93 4.76c-6.25-6.25-16.38-6.25-22.62 0L36.69 27.38c-6.24 6.25-6.24 16.38 0 22.62l86.19 86.18-94.76 94.76c-37.49 37.48-37.49 98.26 0 135.75l117.19 117.19c18.74 18.74 43.31 28.12 67.87 28.12 24.57 0 49.13-9.37 67.87-28.12l221.57-221.57c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.75.01-45.25zm-116.22 70.97H65.93c1.36-3.84 3.57-7.98 7.43-11.83l13.15-13.15 81.61-81.61 58.6 58.6c12.49 12.49 32.75 12.49 45.24 0s12.49-32.75 0-45.24l-58.6-58.6 58.95-58.95 162.44 162.44-48.34 48.34z"/>
</svg>
```

- Move the `path` to the right `transform="translate(40 10)"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" height="400" width="400">
     
     <line   id="svg_1" y2="150" x2="150" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
     
  <line transform="rotate(90)"  id="svg_2" y2="15" x2="15" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="red" fill="none"/> 
  
  <path stroke="#000000" transform="translate(40 10) scale(0.6)" stroke-width="27" fill="#ffffff"  d="M512 320s-64 92.65-64 128c0 35.35 28.66 64 64 64s64-28.65 64-64-64-128-64-128zm-9.37-102.94L294.94 9.37C288.69 3.12 280.5 0 272.31 0s-16.38 3.12-22.62 9.37l-81.58 81.58L81.93 4.76c-6.25-6.25-16.38-6.25-22.62 0L36.69 27.38c-6.24 6.25-6.24 16.38 0 22.62l86.19 86.18-94.76 94.76c-37.49 37.48-37.49 98.26 0 135.75l117.19 117.19c18.74 18.74 43.31 28.12 67.87 28.12 24.57 0 49.13-9.37 67.87-28.12l221.57-221.57c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.75.01-45.25zm-116.22 70.97H65.93c1.36-3.84 3.57-7.98 7.43-11.83l13.15-13.15 81.61-81.61 58.6 58.6c12.49 12.49 32.75 12.49 45.24 0s12.49-32.75 0-45.24l-58.6-58.6 58.95-58.95 162.44 162.44-48.34 48.34z"/>
</svg>
```

- Move the `path` to the down `transform ="translate(10 80)"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" height="400" width="400">
     
     <line   id="svg_1" y2="150" x2="150" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="red" fill="none"/>
     
  <line transform="rotate(90)"  id="svg_2" y2="15" x2="15" y1="0" x1="0" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="red" fill="none"/> 
  
  <path stroke="#000000" transform="translate(10 80) scale(0.6)" stroke-width="27" fill="#ffffff"  d="M512 320s-64 92.65-64 128c0 35.35 28.66 64 64 64s64-28.65 64-64-64-128-64-128zm-9.37-102.94L294.94 9.37C288.69 3.12 280.5 0 272.31 0s-16.38 3.12-22.62 9.37l-81.58 81.58L81.93 4.76c-6.25-6.25-16.38-6.25-22.62 0L36.69 27.38c-6.24 6.25-6.24 16.38 0 22.62l86.19 86.18-94.76 94.76c-37.49 37.48-37.49 98.26 0 135.75l117.19 117.19c18.74 18.74 43.31 28.12 67.87 28.12 24.57 0 49.13-9.37 67.87-28.12l221.57-221.57c12.5-12.5 12.5-32.75.01-45.25zm-116.22 70.97H65.93c1.36-3.84 3.57-7.98 7.43-11.83l13.15-13.15 81.61-81.61 58.6 58.6c12.49 12.49 32.75 12.49 45.24 0s12.49-32.75 0-45.24l-58.6-58.6 58.95-58.95 162.44 162.44-48.34 48.34z"/>
</svg>
```

In both examples, the lines remain in the same place, only the patch is shifted.